# Why is the abbreviation for the Doctor of Optometry O. D.?

Tags: abbreviations

The abbreviation for the Doctor of Optometry is [O.D.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optometry#Scope_of_Practice_3) instead of D.O. - could someone help me understand the reason? Thank you!

"Optometrists are Doctors of Optometry (O.D.) who may prescribe corrective lenses (glasses and contacts) to aid refractive errors (e.g., myopia, hyperopia, presbyopia, astigmatism, double vision)."

Comment: Maybe to keep things simple and no confusion
as O.D degree is related to osteopathy, not sure, whether this is the reason or not. just saying

Comment: I remember when my opthamologist wrote a prescription for drops in my right eye, three times a day. The script was <drug name> O.D. T.I.D. and signed with <doc name>, M.D.  In general, an O.D. (optometrist) can prescribe eye drops, so it's conceivable that the O.D. (optometrist) could write a script for an O.D. (right eye).

Comment: Blame those lousy ancient Italians!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OED has

> **D.** *n.* = Doctor (in *academical degrees,* as a Latin word following, and as English preceding, other initials), as **D.D.** (*Divinitatis Doctor*), Doctor of Divinity, **LL.D.** (*Legum Doctor*), Doctor of Laws, **M.D.** Doctor of Medicine, **Ph.D.,** Doctor of Philosophy, **D.C.L.,** Doctor of Civil Law, **D.Lit., Lit.D.,** Doctor of Literature, **D.Phil.,** Doctor of Philosophy, **D.Sc.,** Doctor of Science.

Note that PhD can also be DPhil; LitD (or LittD) can be DLit; DSc can also be ScD. They are not interchangeable: different universities have different methods. My brother is not MD but DM.

The answer is that OD names the degree in Latin whereas DO is from an English name. Actually, the University of Aston's degree which Wikipedia mentions is not DO at all but [DOptom](https://www2.aston.ac.uk/study/courses/doctor-of-optometry).

It would certainly be useful to know what the Latin phrase is which results in OD, but I can't find any reference online, even from universities which offer that degree.

Comment: I've flagged all the comments on this answer. If you don't like an answer, write your own.

Answer (score 2):

> Optometrists (Honolulu has over 40 of them) may sometimes be confused
> with ophthalmologists because their schools give the degree of
> O.D.—**Optometriae Doctor**, or Doctor of Optometry. However, they are
> not physicians. [*Hawaii Medical Journal and Inter-Island Nurses'
> Bulletin*, Vol. 18](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hawaii_Medical_Journal_and_Inter_island/fPsvAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22Optometriae%20Doctor%22&dq=%22Optometriae%20Doctor%22&printsec=frontcover) (1958) (Google Book snippet)

---

[image]

[A Russian reference](https://www.google.com/books/edition/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD/BsAyAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22Optometriae%20Doctor%22&dq=%22Optometriae%20Doctor%22&printsec=frontcover) (1964) (Google Books snippet)

---

> O.D.  **Optometriae Doctor** "Doctor of Optometry"  ["List of Latin
> Abbreviations"; Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations)

---

However, I find it curious that *none* of the print or online dictionaries that give the Latin for names of academic degrees that I have looked at give any Latin for O.D., Doctor of Optometry. It appears that many of our abbreviations for relatively recent degree names in medical fields retain the English word order, where the  *D*  for *Doctor* comes first e.g.,  DDS (Doctor of Dental Surgery), DMD (Doctor of Medicine in Dentistry or Doctor of Dental Medicine), and DO (Doctor of Osteopathy).

Perhaps, as was noted in comments, it was decided that O.D. would be the *English* abbreviation because  D.O. was already in use (at  least in the U.S.) for the Doctor of Osteopathy degree. I wonder whether *Optometriae Doctor* for O.D. was a "retrofit." :-)

---

With regard to the inevitable abbreviation overloading that Robusto mentioned in a comment, I came across the following while searching for the Latin:

> OD* / right eye (oculus dexter)
> OD  / doctor of optometry
> ...
>
> ---
>
> *Abbreviations use warning. These abbreviations have been judged dangerous and should not be used. [J. Dennerll and P. David; *Medical
> Terminology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Medical_Terminology_A_Programmed_Systems/kTUIAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=O.D.%20should%20not%20be%20used%20for%20right%20eye%20doctor%20of%20optometry&pg=PA586&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

Evidently this admonition fell on deaf ears. I don't think glasses manufacturers and contact lens suppliers get the O.D. after the doctor's name and the right-eye prescription mixed up.

Comment: O.D. is already used for *oculus dextrus*, the right eye. It's hard to find an abbreviation that isn't overloaded.

Comment: @Robusto Thanks--I've added a mention of this particular overloading I came across.

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed explanations!